# Custom export fields in org mode?

Tags: org-mode, org-export

Linux Mint 20

Emacs 28.1

In my org file I use the next standard export fields:

```
#+TITLE: here some descriptions
#+DATE: <2022-11-08 Tue 11:12>
#+AUTHOR: My name
#+EMAIL: my@email.com
#+OPTIONS: num:nill

* POSTPONED 
- State "POSTPONED"  from "IN PROGRESS" [2022-11-21 Mon 15:24]
- State "IN PROGRESS" from              [2022-11-08 Tue 11:13]
```

So the question is:
Can I add custom export fields?

e.g.

```
#+TITLE: here some descriptions
#+DATE: <2022-11-08 Tue 11:12>
#+AUTHOR: My name
#+EMAIL: my@email.com
#+MY_CUSTOM_FIELD_1: some value of custom field1
#+MY_CUSTOM_FIELD_2: some value of custom field2
#+OPTIONS: num:nill
```

Comment: Please clarify: is the request specific to ODT export (as the answer assumes), is it specific to some other backend, or is it a general request for *any* backend?

Comment: @NickD I need export to PDF file

Comment: There are a couple of ways to export to PDF: you can go through ODT, you can go through HTML, or you can go through LaTeX (and perhaps more if you go through pandoc). I guess we'll know what you want by seeing whether you will accept the ODT answer or not.

Comment: What do you expect to use these custom fields for?

Comment: @NickD Export this custom fields to PDF file

Comment: What will they look like in the PDF file? Are they just transcribed directly? Are they used for some kind of calculation? If not, why can't you just write them as text?

Comment: @NickD Not need any calculation. Just simple PDF.

Comment: I really don't understand what you want: you want to have some custom keyword in your Org mode file with some value. *How do you want the PDF output to look like*? If it is just text, *why not write it as just text?*

Comment: @NickD ok, let's write just as text.

Comment: IOW, you don't need any special treatment, so the question should be closed.

Comment: I am not convinced that the OP is talking about any of this. And everything he has said so far indicates otherwise, at least to me. At the very least, the question needs "details and clarity".